# Qt remove character from QLineEdit if its not hexadecimal

Tags: c++, string, qt

I have a QLineEdit in my Qt application which needs to take a hexadecimal value as an input. I want the application to display a warning Message box if the character entered is not hexadecimal and delete the invalid character from the QLineEdit. This check has to be performed at the entry of each character in the QLineEdit. So far I have got this:

```
void MemoryTestWindow::on_lineEditAddress1_textChanged(const QString &arg1)
{
        QString text1=ui->lineEditAddress1->text();
        int len=text1.length();
        QChar ch=text1.at(len-1).toUpper();
        if(!((ch>='A'&& ch<='F')|| (ch>='0' && ch<='9')))
        {
            text1.remove(len-1,1);
            //*arg1="";
            QMessageBox::warning(this,"Invalid Character!","Please enter hexadecimal characters 0-9, A-F");

        }

}
```

I am using the textChanged slot of the QLineEdit since I need to perform the check after each character entry. I can't figure how to change the value in QLineEdit i.e. the last invalid character should be deleted after clicking 'OK' in the warning Message box. How can I do this?

Comment: Maybe you have to set the line edit's text (modified) again after closing message box? For example, by calling `ui->lineEditAddress1->setText(text1);`.

Comment: @vahancho this gives an error which I believe is because setText will again reflect on textChanged function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to do this is to use a [QValidator](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qvalidator.html)

```
 QRegExpValidator *v = new QRegExpValidator("[a-fA-F0-9]*", this); // or QRegularExpressionValidator
 ui->lineEdit->setValidator(v);
```

As `QValidator` inherits `QObject` you can make it emit a signal to detect when the user type an invalid character:

```
class Validator : public QRegExpValidator
{
    Q_OBJECT
    public:
        Validator(const QRegExp &rx, QObject *parent = nullptr) : 
            QRegExpValidator(rx, parent)
        {}

        State validate(QString &input, int &pos) const override
        {
            State state = QRegExpValidator::validate(input, pos);
            if (state == Invalid)
                emit error();
            return state;
        }
    signals:
        void error();
}
```

And then you just have to connect to `error()` to show the error to the user:

```
 Validator *v = new Validator ("[a-fA-F0-9]*", this);
 ui->lineEdit->setValidator(v);
 connect(v, &Validator::error, this, &MyClass::handleWrongInput); 
 // Where handleWrongInput is the slot that handles the error and eventually show an error message
```

### Addendum

If in `MyClass::handleWrongInput()`, you do something that causes the `QLineEdit` to recall `QValidator::validate()`, like changing the keyboard focus, you will create a loop as the first call to `validate()` still has not returned. To fix this, you should let the call to `validate()` return before calling `MyClass::handleWrongInput()`.

To do so the easiest solution is to use queued connection:

```
connect(v, &Validator::error, this, &MyClass::handleWrongInput, Qt::QueuedConnection);
```

Comment: I am assuming you meant `v` instead of `c` in the `connect` function call?

Comment: This is working but its emitting the signal 3 times makin the error box appear 3 times instead of one.

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwal Yes, it is supposed to be `v`. Also I just tested with Qt 5.9 on Linux and `validate()` is called only one time per key press, therefore `error()` is emitted just once per key press. If you slot is called more than once, it could be because you connected it more than once or it could be because in your version of Qt `validate()` is called 3 times.

Comment: Thanks. I checked. The issue was that in the function WrongInput(), I was displaying a MessageBox to display warning. On clicking OK on this box it was again validating the text in the LineEdit. Added `lineEdit->backspace()` before displaying warning and it got fixed.

Comment: One last thing. I have multiple such LineEdits in my application and Ideally I would like to use the same handleWrongInput() for all of them. Is there any way I can pass an argument to know which signal is emitting the error(considering I assign different signals for each lineEdit like v1,v2,...)

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwal The `QLineEdit` will revalidate its content when it looses focus. Also when you display the error message, the `validate()` has not yet returned and the text hasn't been fixed. So when you click OK you have a new error box because the `QlineEdit` is trying to revalidate the same erroneous text. Calling `backspace()` is not a good solution, it will not work when the user paste text longer than a single character (and also it is ugly design wise). The solution is to make the connection queued (see edited answer).

Comment: @AbhishekAgarwal You can retrieve the object that send a signal using the `sender()` function from the slot. So you can retrieve which validator sent the signal. Now you need to retrieve the line edit from the validator, this can be done in various ways using hash tables or the QObject parent-child relationship. But this requires having one validator for each line edit (Qt support setting the same validator on multiple line edits). Alternatively you could use `QApplication::focusWidget()`, assuming you did not mess the focus, it should still be on the lineedit.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 5):

Don't reinvent the wheel ;) You will probably have better results using the Qt tools designed to achieve what you want.

[QLineEdit::mask](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#inputMask-prop) let you define what characters are allowed in your edit control. In particular, defining a mask using `H` chars will let you determine how many hexadecimal characters are allowed in the control.

If this is not enough to what you want to do, looks around [validators](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlineedit.html#setValidator) for more complex and complete validation process.

Comment: Thanks! This is very helpful; only mask won't allow me to pop-up that warning message box. Trying to make do with validators

Answer (score 1):

What about using `ui->lineEditAddress1->setText(text1.remove(len-1, 1))`? Also, not sure if that has any chance to work, but maybe `backspace()` method will work just fine?

http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlineedit.html#backspace

Comment: None of the methods to modify the text inside the QlineEdit would work here as it would again trigger the textChanged slot. I have tried this in the code and I assume this is the reason why its not working.

Comment: If it removes the last, invalid character, it won't matter if signal will be emitted again, since it will just check the previous character (last valid). If you don't use masks or validators, it will fire the `textChanged` no matter what, since both of those methods use `setText()`, though with `backspace()` it's not emitted directly.